# NoSuchElementException in ChiSqSelector fit method (version 1.6.0)

Tags: apache-spark, feature-selection, apache-spark-mllib, chi-squared, apache-spark-ml

I'm running into an error that's not making a lot of sense to me, and couldn't find sufficient info on the web to answer it myself.

I've written code to generate a list of (String, ArrayBuffer[String]) pairs and then use HashingTF to convert the features column to vectors (bc it's for NLP research on parsing where I end up with a whole lot of unique features; long story). Then I convert the string labels using StringIndexer. I get the "key not found" error when running ChiSqSelector.fit on the training data. The stack trace points to a hashmap lookup in ChiSqTest for labels. This struck me as strange, because I could sort of reason that perhaps I was using it wrong and had not somehow accounted for unseen labels -- except this was the fit method on training data.

Anyway, here's the interesting bit of my code followed by the important part of the stack trace. Any help would be very much appreciated!!

```scala
val parSdp = sc.parallelize(sdp.take(10)) // it dies on a small amount of data
val insts: RDD[(String, ArrayBuffer[String])] =
    parSdp.flatMap(x=> TrainTest.transformGraphSpark(x))

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol("labels")
    .setOutputCol("labelIndex")

val instDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(insts)
    .toDF("labels","feats")
val hash = new HashingTF()
    .setInputCol("feats")
    .setOutputCol("hashedFeats")
    .setNumFeatures(1000000)
val readyDF = hash.transform(indexer
    .fit(instDF)
    .transform(instDF))

val selector = new ChiSqSelector()
    .setNumTopFeatures(100)
    .setFeaturesCol("hashedFeats")
    .setLabelCol("labelIndex")
    .setOutputCol("selectedFeatures")

val Array(training, dev,test) = readyDF.randomSplit(Array(0.8,0.1,0.1), seed = 12345)

val chisq = selector.fit(training)
```

And the stack trace:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 23.0                           
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTest$$anonfun$chiSquaredFeatures$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ChiSqTest.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTest$$anonfun$chiSquaredFeatures$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ChiSqTest.scala:129)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTest$$anonfun$chiSquaredFeatures$4.apply(ChiSqTest.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTest$$anonfun$chiSquaredFeatures$4.apply(ChiSqTest.scala:125)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTest$.chiSquaredFeatures(ChiSqTest.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics$.chiSqTest(Statistics.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.ChiSqSelector.fit(ChiSqSelector.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelector.fit(ChiSqSelector.scala:86)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:89)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:122)
    ... etc etc
```

I also realized that by changing the size of sdp.take larger (to 100) above I get a different error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Chi-squared statistic undefined for input matrix due to0 sum in column [4].
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTest$.chiSquaredMatrix(ChiSqTest.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTest$$anonfun$chiSquaredFeatures$4.apply(ChiSqTest.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTest$$anonfun$chiSquaredFeatures$4.apply(ChiSqTest.scala:125)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTest$.chiSquaredFeatures(ChiSqTest.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics$.chiSqTest(Statistics.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.ChiSqSelector.fit(ChiSqSelector.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelector.fit(ChiSqSelector.scala:86)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:96)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:130)
```

Comment: Looking at the source code for ChiSqTest.scala (line 131), this error really seems impossible. As the comment says "Do this only once for the first column [set the labels map] since labels are invariant across features".

Comment: Briefly I thought I had fixed it when I noticed that I originally split the data by 0.9, 0.1, and 0.1. Fixing that brought up another error which I have added to the question above.  Changing the size of sdp.take brought the original error back.